# I cannot configure my package.js file for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I type "npm start" in command prompt and there is an error

This is the error:

> Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found. Alternatively, run
>   'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

And this is the code in my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "reactredux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && copy src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && copy src/index.html dist/index.html"
    },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "NikolaMilicevic",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting this when you run 'build'? How did you come to having your scripts.build command? It's a problem with how you are running webpack; I don't have a lot of experience with it myself, but I would start by Googling how to use it and the error you're getting. Did you use npm/yarn to install everything?

Comment: What do you do that causes this error? Are you running some command? If so, what is it? Please show an exact session in your terminal.

Comment: Wher I run in npm i write npm start to run a build and that is when i get error

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's the 'start' in the package.json, it calls 'npm run build' which uses webpack, that is the command that is failing. There is something wrong with the way webpack is being used.

Comment: @NikolaMilicevic Please [edit] your question to show the command you run that causes the error.

Comment: what does your webpack.config.js look like?

Comment: here is my webpack.config.js file      var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
 entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
 output: {
  path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
  filename: "bundle.js",
  publicPath: "/app/"
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [
  {
   test: /\.js?/,
   include: SRC_DIR,
   loader: "babel-loader",
   query: {
    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
   }
  }
  ]
 }
};

module.export = config;

Comment: @NikolaMilicevic edit your questions to include the webpack config, it's difficult to read in its current format.